# Conditional References in HAPI FHIR

Tags: hapi, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

HL7 FHIR Release 3 (STU) introduced the concept of **Conditional References** in transaction bundles:

> When constructing the bundle, the client may not know the logical id
> of a resource, but it may know identifying information - e.g. an
> identifier. This situation arises commonly when building transactions
> from v2 messages. The client could resolve that identifier to a
> logical id using a search, but that would mean that the resolution to
> a logical id does not occur within the same transaction as the commit
> (as well as significantly complicating the client). Because of this,
> in a transaction (and only in a transaction), references to resources
> may be replaced by a search URI that describes how to find the correct
> reference:

```xml
<Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
    <id value="20160113160203" />
    <type value="transaction" />
    <entry>
        <fullUrl value="urn:uuid:c72aa430-2ddc-456e-7a09-dea8264671d8" />
        <resource>
            <Observation>
                <subject>
                    <reference value="Patient?identifier=12345" />
                </subject>
                <!-- rest of resource omitted -->
            </Observation>
        </resource>
        <request>
            <method value="POST" />
        </request>
    </entry>
</Bundle>
```

> The search URI is relative to the server's [base] path, and always
> starts with a resource type: `[type]:?parameters....` Only filtering
> parameters are allowed; none of the parameters that control the return
> of resources are relevant.
>
> When processing transactions, servers SHALL:

- check all references for search URIs
- For search URIs, use the search to locate matching resources
- if there are no matches, or multiple matches, the transaction fails, and an error is returned to the user
- if there is a single match, the server replaces the search URI with a reference to the matching resource

*... quoted from [2.21.0.17.2 Transaction Processing Rules](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/http.html#2.21.0.17.2)*

I found this concept of conditional references very useful and I would like to use it in my HAPI FHIR client/server app. It seems that it is not supported. Such transaction bundle is refused by server with following error messages:

Client:

> HTTP 400 Bad Request: Invalid resource reference found at `path[Observation.subject]` - Does not contain resource type - `Patient?identifier=12345`

```
Exception in thread "main" ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request: Invalid resource reference found at path[Observation.subject] - Does not contain resource type - Patient?identifier=12345
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.exceptions.BaseServerResponseException.newInstance(BaseServerResponseException.java:307)
    at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.client.BaseClient.invokeClient(BaseClient.java:290)
    at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.client.GenericClient$BaseClientExecutable.invoke(GenericClient.java:637)
    at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.client.GenericClient$TransactionExecutable.execute(GenericClient.java:2209)
```

Server log:

> WARN  c.u.f.r.s.i.ExceptionHandlingInterceptor [ExceptionHandlingInterceptor.java:135] Failure during REST processing: ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: Invalid resource reference found at `path[Observation.subject]` - Does not contain resource type - `Patient?identifier=12345`

So my question is:

Is it possible to use conditional references with HAPI FHIR JPA server?

Or if it is not possible, is there work around? Can I use same conditional operation which would resolve the reference or fail if the reference target doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I discovered that it is possible even with HAPI FHIR vesion `2.2` simply by adding following option to the server `DaoConfig`:

```
ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.dao.DaoConfig.setAllowInlineMatchUrlReferences(true)
```

> Should references containing match URLs be resolved and replaced in
>   create and update operations. For example, if this property is set to
>   true and a resource is created containing a reference to
>   `Patient?identifier=12345`, this is reference match URL will be
>   resolved and replaced according to the usual match URL rules.
>
> Default is `false` for now, as this is an experimental feature.

See the source code here: [github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir](https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir/blob/v2.3/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-base/src/main/java/ca/uhn/fhir/jpa/dao/DaoConfig.java#L304)